# How OSX Built-in Force Quit Application Get its app list?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsworkspace

I am trying to get all running applications that have window interface, and I find the application list from the **Force Quit Application Utility** is pretty ideal.

[image]

But I don't know how to implement it, have tried [NSWorkSpace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html), which gives me all the running app including a lot others.

So how to archive this function? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I decide to use `NSWorkspace.runningApplications` still, but filter the results using `Bundle URL` field and `ownsMenuBar` with some pre-defined rules.

Little busy these days, but I will post my result after try as soon as possible. Here is a useful sample app: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AppList/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, sayen, this worked great for me.

Here's the Swift code I used to force-quit After Effects:

```
let runningApps = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications
if let aeApp = runningApps.filter( { ($0.bundleIdentifier != nil) && ($0.bundleIdentifier! == "com.adobe.AfterEffects") }).first {
    aeApp.forceTerminate()
}
```

Note that in Swift, the bundle identifier is an optional.